# how to make square subplots in matplotlib with heatmaps?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to make a simple subplot with a dendrogram in one subplot and a heat map in another, while maintaining square axes. I try the following:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
cm = matplotlib.cm.Blues
X = np.random.random([5,5])
pmat = pdist(X, "euclidean")
linkmat = linkage(pmat)
dendrogram(linkmat)
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
Y = np.random.random([6,6])
plt.xticks(arange(0.5, 7.5, 1))
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(labels)
plt.pcolor(Y)
plt.colorbar()
```

this yields the following:

[image]

but the problems are that the axes are not square, and the colorbar is considered part of the second subplot. I'd like it instead to hang outside the plot, and make it so the dendrogram box and the heatmap box are both square and aligned with each other (i.e. same size.)

I tried using `aspect='equal'` to get square axes when calling `subplot` as the documentation suggests, but this ruined the plot, giving this...

[image]

if I try to use `plt.axis('equal')` after each subplot instead of `aspect='equal'`, it strangely squares the heatmap but not its bounding box (see below), while destroying the dendrogram altogether and also messing up the alignment of the xtick labels.... - giving rise to this mess:

[image]

how can this be fixed? to summarize, I'm trying to plot something very simple: a square dendrogram in the top subplot, and a square heatmap in the bottom subplot, with the color bar on the right. nothing fancy.

finally, more general question: is there a general rule / principle to follow to force matplotlib to *always* make axes square? I cannot think of a single case where I don't want square axes but it's usually not the default behavior. I'd like to force all plots to be square if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@HYRY's answer is very good and deserves all the credit. But to finish off the answer about lining the squared plots up nicely, you could trick matplotlib into thinking that both plots have colorbars, only making the first one invisible:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,7))
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
cm = matplotlib.cm.Blues
X = np.random.random([5,5])
pmat = pdist(X, "euclidean")
linkmat = linkage(pmat)
dendrogram(linkmat)
x0,x1 = ax1.get_xlim()
y0,y1 = ax1.get_ylim()
ax1.set_aspect((x1-x0)/(y1-y0))

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2, aspect=1)
labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
Y = np.random.random([6,6])
plt.xticks(arange(0.5, 7.5, 1))
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(labels)
plt.pcolor(Y)
plt.colorbar()

# add a colorbar to the first plot and immediately make it invisible
cb = plt.colorbar(ax=ax1)
cb.ax.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image: code output]

Answer (score 15):

aspect="equal" mean the same length in data space will be the same length in screen space, but in your top axe, the data ranges of xaxis and yaxis are not the same, so it will not be a square. To fix this problem, you can set the aspect to the ratio of xaxis range and yaxis range:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,7))
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
cm = matplotlib.cm.Blues
X = np.random.random([5,5])
pmat = pdist(X, "euclidean")
linkmat = linkage(pmat)
dendrogram(linkmat)
x0,x1 = ax1.get_xlim()
y0,y1 = ax1.get_ylim()
ax1.set_aspect((x1-x0)/(y1-y0))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2, aspect=1)
labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
Y = np.random.random([6,6])
plt.xticks(arange(0.5, 7.5, 1))
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(labels)
plt.pcolor(Y)
plt.colorbar()
```

Here is the output:

[image]

To location the colorbar we need write a ColorBarLocator Class, the pad and width argument are in pixel unit,

- **pad**: set the space between the axes and it's colobar
- **width**: the width of the colorbar

replace `plt.colorbar()` with the following code:

```
class ColorBarLocator(object):
    def __init__(self, pax, pad=5, width=10):
        self.pax = pax
        self.pad = pad
        self.width = width

    def __call__(self, ax, renderer):
        x, y, w, h = self.pax.get_position().bounds
        fig = self.pax.get_figure()
        inv_trans = fig.transFigure.inverted()
        pad, _ = inv_trans.transform([self.pad, 0])
        width, _ = inv_trans.transform([self.width, 0])
        return [x+w+pad, y, width, h]

cax = fig.add_axes([0,0,0,0], axes_locator=ColorBarLocator(ax2))
plt.colorbar(cax = cax)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your plots are still not aligned like regular subplots.  The bounding boxes for the top and bottom are not aligned.  I'd like them to be vertically aligned with the color back hanging off to the right, kind of like you have it but not misaligned. Any ideas on this?

Comment: thanks for your answer - it's exactly the right output but the code seems immensely complex! is there an easier way? it seems like you have to be one of the matplotlib developers to know how to write something like this, just to get a color bar to line up...

Comment: Here are some examples, but I think they are difficult to understand too:
 http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/axes_grid/demo_colorbar_with_inset_locator.html http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/axes_grid/demo_axes_divider.html

Comment: I know those examples well but they don't apply I believe when there's a dendrogram in the other subplot, since that breaks things for some reason.

Comment: do you know why matplotlib messes up the vertical alignment of the x labels in the bottom subplot? why aren't `a, b, c, d, e, f` all aligned?

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, you need to take the absolute value of arguments to `.set_aspect`:

```
x0,x1 = ax1.get_xlim()
y0,y1 = ax1.get_ylim()
ax1.set_aspect(abs(x1-x0)/abs(y1-y0))
```