# How to make a rectangle plot with two square sublots using maptlotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Function `matplotlib.pyplot.subplot` allows to make subplots. I want to obtain two square subplots in a rectangle plot. If I use something like `subplot(1,2,1)` and `subplot(1,2,2)` then I get two rectangle subplots in a square plot. How to make it another way around?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893414/how-to-make-square-subplots-in-matplotlib-with-heatmaps

Comment: Thanks, I got solution from there. I just need to add next line 
`fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,7))`