# Resizing scipy dendrogram and matplotlib pcolor subplots while keeping alignment

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, heatmap, dendrogram

### Goal

Make a dendrogram connected to a heatmap like the ones matlab makes;

[image]

Or like [this plotly example](https://plot.ly/python/dendrogram/?utm_source=mailchimp-jan-2015&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=generalemail-jan2015&utm_term=dendrogram-heatmap) without the fancy javascript using just scipy and matplotlib.

Building off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893414/how-to-make-square-subplots-in-matplotlib-with-heatmaps?answertab=votes) I derived the following code;

### INPUT

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange

# Create the figure and set it's size.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,7))

# Create the first subplot in the figure. 
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)

# Set to your favorite colormap.
cm = matplotlib.cm.viridis

# Create array of random numbers.
X = np.random.random([6,300])

# Create a linkage object.
linkmat = linkage(X)

# Make a dendrogram from the linkage object.
dendrogram(linkmat)

# Use the x and y limits to set the aspect.
x0,x1 = ax1.get_xlim()
y0,y1 = ax1.get_ylim()
ax1.set_aspect((x1-x0)/(y1-y0))


# Remove the ticks on the x-axis. 
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom='off', top='off', labelbottom='off')

# Create the second subplot.
ax2 = plt.subplot(212)

labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

plt.xticks(arange(0.5, 7.5, 1))

plt.gca().set_xticklabels(labels)

plt.pcolor(X.T)

x0,x1 = ax2.get_xlim()
y0,y1 = ax2.get_ylim()

ax2.set_aspect((x1-x0)/(y1-y0))

# Insert the color scale
plt.colorbar()
cb = plt.colorbar(ax=ax1)
cb.ax.set_visible(False)

# Make the vertical distance between plots equal to zero 
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

### OUTPUT

[image]

### Question

How can I **reduce** the height of dendrogram by 50% and **increase** the height of the heatmap by 50% while maintaining their current alignment?

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/heatmapcluster

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `subplot2grid({params})` instead of `subplot()` since you can tell how many grid it will occupy

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange

# Create the figure and set it's size.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,7))

# Create the first subplot in the figure. 
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 1), (0, 0), rowspan= 1, colspan=1)

# Set to your favorite colormap.
cm = matplotlib.cm.viridis

# Create array of random numbers.
X = np.random.random([6,300])

# Create a linkage object.
linkmat = linkage(X)

# Make a dendrogram from the linkage object.
dendrogram(linkmat)

# Use the x and y limits to set the aspect.
x0,x1 = ax1.get_xlim()
y0,y1 = ax1.get_ylim()
#ax1.set_aspect((x1-x0)/(y1-y0))


# Remove the ticks on the x-axis. 
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom='off', top='off', labelbottom='off')

# Create the second subplot.
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 1), (1, 0), rowspan= 2, colspan=1)

labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

plt.xticks(arange(0.5, 7.5, 1))

plt.gca().set_xticklabels(labels)

plt.pcolor(X.T)

x0,x1 = ax2.get_xlim()
y0,y1 = ax2.get_ylim()

#ax2.set_aspect((x1-x0)/(y1-y0))

# Insert the color scale
plt.colorbar()
cb = plt.colorbar(ax=ax1)
cb.ax.set_visible(False)

# Make the vertical distance between plots equal to zero 
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]